# how to map array of observable objects and properties(fields) to just properties?

Tags: arrays, rxjs, mapping, observable

**I am currently getting a response from server in this form.**

```
{
    plateNumber: string;
    vehicleId: number;
    garage: {
        garageName: string;
    };
    vehicleType: {
        vehicleType: string;
    };
    vehicleStatus: {
        status: string;
    };
    vehicleModel: {
        vehicleModelName: string;
    };
    vehicleOwner: {
        ownerName: string;
    };
    contactPhone: number;
    techInspectDueDate: Date;
    additionalInfo: string;
    lastDriver: string;
}
```

**but want to get only properties(fields). Meaning just strings and numbers.**

```
{
    plateNumber: string;
    vehicleId: number;
    garageName: string;
    vehicleType: string;
    status: string;
    vehicleModelName: string;
    ownerName: string;
    contactPhone: number;
    techInspectDueDate: Date;
    additionalInfo: string;
    lastDriver: string;
}
```

Currently I am using HTTP post response to get objects from server.

```
 getVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle[]> {
    const url = `${this.serviceUrl}`;
    return this.http.post<Vehicle[]>(url, {} );
  }
```

I need to map the response while checking if the object has these specific fields( vehicleType, status, vehicleModelName, ownerName, garageName). **How do I map the response when I'm not sure if object has these fields or if it's already the value that I need (e.x. plateNumber)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use map and return whatever you want.

```
 getVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle[]> {
    const url = `${this.serviceUrl}`;
    return this.http.post<Vehicle[]>(url, {}).pipe(
      map(vehicles => vehicles.map(vehicle => {
        return {
          plateNumber: vehicle.plateNumber;
          vehicleId: vehicle.vehicleId;
          garageName: vehicle.garage.garageName;
          //...map all other fields manually
        };
      })),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider a solution along these lines

```
getVehicles().pipe(
  map(vehiclesArray => vehiclesArray.map(vehicle => getProperties(vehicle))
  )
)
```

where `getProperties` is a method you have to write which returns the object you want to have.

Consider that the first occurrence of `map` is the pipeable operator offered by RxJS, while the second is the method of Array.

You have also to decide how to behave in case you do not find the properties you are looking for.